# How do you define constants with the same name but for differents networks?

Tags: anchor, rust

I'd like to define something like:

```
pub mod mints {
    use solana_program::{pubkey, pubkey::Pubkey};
    pub const USDC: Pubkey = pubkey!("key");
}
```

But then be able to access it with `mints::USDC` and have the value be environment dependent.

Is this possible? How do I achieve this with either just solana/rust or within Anchor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally use the [`env!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.env.html) and [`option_env!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.option_env.html) macros, then set an environment variable e.g. `MAINNET` when I want to build for mainnet and assume devnet otherwise.

Combined with [`just`](https://github.com/casey/just) to set env-vars it works pretty well, e.g. you can setup a command `just build-bpf-mainnet` as `MAINNET=1 cargo build-bpf`

This way it's pretty easy to setup constants for different mints:

```
pub fn is_mainnet() -> bool {
    option_env!("MAINNET").is_some()
}

pub struct Mint {
    dev: Pubkey,
    main: Pubkey,
}

impl Mint {
    pub fn pubkey(&self) -> Pubkey {
        if is_mainnet() {
            self.main
        } else {
            self.dev
        }
    }
}

pub const USDC: Mint = Mint {
    main: pubkey!("EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v"),
    dev: pubkey!("4zMMC9srt5Ri5X14GAgXhaHii3GnPAEERYPJgZJDncDU"),
};

pub const LIKE: Mint = Mint {
    main: pubkey!("3bRTivrVsitbmCTGtqwp7hxXPsybkjn4XLNtPsHqa3zR"),
    dev: pubkey!("8KM7nEzUebxtnJ1BRbbnh58Bnm1ZCtmCsp1xW1zYsuWp"),
};
```

I tried looking for a way for on-chain programs to determine dev/local/mainnet recently but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 0):

this library might might help?

[confy](https://github.com/rust-cli/confy)

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps to specialize this a bit more: Is it possible for environment detection to happen when the code is deployed? If I deploy to mainnet a different set of constants is defined as opposed to local dev?